# how to style the fallback content of the canvas element?

Tags: css, html, html5-canvas

As the specification states:

```
The contents of the canvas element, if any, are the element's fallback content.
```

So, I thought it would be reasonable to do something like this:

```
<head>           
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    if (canvas != null)
    {
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
            image   = canvas.querySelector("img");

        // do something special with 'context' and 'image'
    }
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas>
        <img class="myImageType" style="border: 1px solid #777;" src="file">
    </canvas>
</body>
```

As you can see, I don't recreate the image, but use the nested one. It doesn't make sense to me, to create a new one.
However, the style is not applied to the nested image element.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:
I need to set the style for `canvas` and the nested `img` or add the same `class` to them:

```
<body>
    <canvas class="myImageType">
        <img class="myImageType">
    </canvas>
</body>
```